# iOS newbie: search id from a local json file then make request to server

Tags: ios, json, swift, swift2, alamofire

I am learning iOS development. Currently, I started my hobby project which is a weather foracast app. I have found a open REST API, I can send request to get weather data for a city.

The REST API needs me to send request with **city id** instead of city name & it provides me a 20MB json file which contains city objects with fields `city_id`, `city_name`, `longitude`, `latitude`. I know I should create a `City` class to have those fields.

My app is supposed to allow user to input the city name, then, my app make request with the corresponding **city id**. My question is a about the best practice for this:

1. Since I need all city ids, should I download the 20MB json file & embed it to my app? Does that mean my app size would be larger than 20MB ? Any better practice to handle this?
2. If I have to put the 20MB json file in my project, what is the best way to parse the content to a list of `City` programmatically?
3. If user input one city name, I feel if I scan all the cities in the json file, it is inefficient, what could be the efficient way to find the city id for the city name (without scanning all the 20MB json)?

[==== THE OPEN REST API ===](http://openweathermap.org/current)

Comment: provide the open REST API so I can have a look at it

Comment: You can seed a data model with the JSON file, if you use something like Core Data, you can use it's API to query, manage, etc.

Comment: 20MB is a pretty huge file to bundle if it isn't absolutely necessary. Are you sure there isn't a network call you can make to trade a city name for an ID? Can you post a link to the documentation?

Comment: @Dare, from what I see, I don't find a network call for city id, I have provided the link to that open REST API, could you please take a look? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to include the JSON in your app. In fact, I highly recommend against doing so. This is according to the documentation:

Description:

You can call by city name or city name and country code. API responds with a list of results that match a searching word.
API call:

api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={city name}

api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={city name},{country code}

Parameters:

q city name and country code divided by comma, use ISO 3166 country codes

Examples of API calls:

api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London

api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London,uk

Given this information, you can send a request to the API like the example given: api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=London

The response should include the necessary data to make a subsequent call for the weather forecast.

No need to include 20MB of noise in your app bundle.

Comment: Thanks, since they say searching by city name doesn't provide precise data compare with searching by city id. That's why I try to use city id but get stuck with handling the 20MB city json file

Comment: The fact of the matter is there are cities around the world that have the same name. This is where precision suffers. Bundling a file that you then query yourself will not solve this problem. City IDs are unique. If you plan to hardcode a single city ID, then this would work fine. Since you intend to allow users to enter a city name, you will end up doing much more work to provide a local match when the API already does this for you.

Comment: yep, you are right, I am going to use the city name then, less trouble.

Answer (score 0):

1. I'd create an array of `City` objects and parse the data into each `City` object (assuming you need all of them. If not, you'll have to find a way to parse out the ones youd on't want.) As long as you're not writing these to storage it shouldn't increase your app size, it may take a bit to download and parse depending on the methods you use, but that's all part of the fun of optimizing.
2. There are many JSON parsing iOS libraries, I have the most experience using `RestKit` to make network requests, and that includes a JSON to Objective-C Object parser built right in, it's super easy. Basically, do some research on JSON parser libraries and pick the one that best suits your needs. You shouldn't need to parse it yourself.
3. I'd create an `NSDictionary` with the `city_name` as your keys, and the `city_id` as your values. Then to retrieve the `city_id` simply call `[dictionary objectForKey:enteredCity]` (replacing with your actual variable names, of course)

Comment: I think you don't get my point of my 1st question, I mean I need anyhow to bundle the 20MB json first to my project first, then I can parse it to a large list of City programmatically, that is what I am saying in my question. I feel it is large and inefficient. I can't download the 20MB json at runtime when app is running because it is more inefficient.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that they are asking you to bundle and not burden their server with requests for the 20mb file that doesn't seem to change much.

I would make a script that you run on your dev machine that turns this into a sqlite db (or some other serialized format).  Don't bundle the JSON and parse at runtime --- turn it into something queryable at runtime.